# Spring MVC - post group of input type text as object list

Tags: java, spring, forms, post, mustache

I'm using spring mvc. I need to binding a group of input type as list java side.

With list of primitive type it works:

```
<li>
    <input type="hidden" name="ids" value="1"/>
</li>
<li>
    <input type="hidden" name="ids" value="2"/>
</li>
```

Business side, in the method that catch form submit, this is the object that is bound with @ModelAttribute annotation.

```
...
private List<long> ids;
...
```

and ids = [1, 2]

But, if I have a list of object instead of primitive type like:

```
...
private List<Person> people; //Person has name and surname attribute 
...
```

If I write:

```
<li>
    //Not works neither with name="people.name" or name="people[0].name":
    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="James"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="surname" value="Bond"/>
</li>
<li>
    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="Will"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="surname" value="Smith"/>
</li>
```

It not works.

UPDATE: with "It not works" I mean that the post submit is correctly catched by the method, but the people list is empty. The class that binds the form is a simple java class with get and set method.

The html form is declared as:

```
<form method="post" id="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: please include the whole class and define "it not works". your question is a bit hard to read and understand at this point

Comment: what do you use for generating the view? JSP? Thymeleaf?

Comment: @dienerd update

Comment: @KamilPiwowarski, I'm using mustache template